# Android Push Notifications with GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm Developing a simple app that receives the GCM push messages from the PHP server. The App and Server works fine, even with multiple push messages. The only thing I want to add in the app is, If a push message is not received within few seconds, lets say 5seconds, i want my app to Toast a message saying "Network error". I'm using "WakefulBrodcastReceiver" for receiving the push messages. except for this, all code is working fine, as I expect it to.

Working:
Pressing a button notifies the server, that App is ready for receiving the notifications.
Now, i'm having two scenarios,

1. App haven't received any push message, 5 seconds are passed by since the button press event, SHOW THE TOAST.
2. I've already received few push messages, 5 seconds are passed by since i've received the last message, SHOW THE TOAST.

following code snippet is written in GCM Handler class, which handles the push messages.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e("HANDLER", "inside run()");
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network Error", 1000).show();
    }
}, Constants.TIME_OUT);
```

The value of Constants.TIME_OUT is 5000,
the Toast or the Log never displayed.

Comment: And how the app would know if a push has been sent and not received?

Comment: @Udi : Question edited, please check.

Comment: So why not just keep a variable of the last received push and then use a Handler for example which runs every X seconds and checks the status (this will be activated only after the button was pressed)?

Comment: i've tried that already, but the WakefulIntent is finishing execution and the postDelayed code never gets executed.

Comment: Not really, I will write a short example

Comment: Is your GCM Handler class a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: No, the GCMHandler class extends IntentService, and the code is written in "onHandleIntent()"

Comment: thanks @bigO for the corrections.

Comment: As I recall when onHandleIntent in invoked the service gets destroyed

Comment: @UdiI you're correct, after `onHandleIntent` returns (and there's no more intents in the queue to be handled), the service is shut down and the Looper will stop which prevents the delayed runnable being run eventually.

Comment: So, is there any work around for this...???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I wanted to do was, to show a "Check network connection" message if the app don't receive a Push notification from PHP server in 5 seconds.
as [Udi I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500105/udi-i) and [Zharf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/857853/zharf) stated, When onHandleIntent returns, the service Shuts down, and so does the delayed runnings. So, I tried the other way.
I used Timer Task.
The code is,

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;

public static void startTimer(Context context) {
    timer = new Timer();
    initializeTimerTask(context);
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000);  //Time in miliSeconds
}

public static void stopTimer(){
    if(timer != null)
        timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}

public static void initializeTimerTask(final Context context){
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Check Network connection...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From your initial question, it seems like you are setting the timer in the receiver. Shouldn't the timer be set on the button click?

Comment: i thought to do it, but i couldn't figure out how to communicate between the activity and receiver, because i want to popup a message only if the next message is not received withing 5 seconds, not otherwise. i.e. the timer should be restarted in case of a new push message.

Comment: What do you mean by "only if the next message is not received" are there more than one message per button click?

Comment: i click the button and sends a message to server, that device is ready for receiving the push messages. the server can and will send multiple push messages. until another button is pressed.